# Errors in Gnuplot figures after converting DVI to PS/PDF

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, gnuplot, dvips

I use Gnuplot to generate my figures (with "set terminal postscript eps"). When I insert the figures into my LaTeX document and compile it using the standard compiler `latex`(?), everything looks fine. However, when I convert the DVI file to PS (and subsequently to PDF), a lot of things are missing -- letters, labels, axes -- see example screenshot:

[image: Example screenshot]

For example, the outermost bars have a label with a number, the bar titles are supposed to be "majority" and "entropy", and so on.

What could be the issue? Font problem? Version problem?

Comment: Please don't downvote without leaving a comment explaining how the question can be improved, especially if it's the first question of a new user.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) to familiarize yourself further with our format. To clarify your question, you should add a [MWE (minimal working example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077) of what works.

Comment: Try `set terminal postscript enhanced` or `set terminal pdfcairo enhanced` in gnuplot, **not** `set terminal postscript eps`, but I fear, this question is off-topic. Try to use the correct font encoding in gnuplot, too

Comment: Can you make the `eps` file available for download and add a link here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to compile your document directly to a pdf.
The compiler is called `pdflatex`. There you need the package `epstopdf` which has to come after the package `graphicx` for correct compilation of your eps graphics.
You have to hand over to the compiler the statement `pdflatex --shell-escape`.
Maybe you need also to add `--enable-write18`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{test.eps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite true. I also used pdflatex and the results looks perfectly fine. The problem I encountered was that the resulting PDF could not be opened on any machine, and I have no idea what the issue might be. I don't think it's a font issue since pdffonts tells me that all fonts are embedded.

Comment: Did you look at the intermediate PDF, created by the package `epstopdf`? If this PDF file opens correctly, then it is a problem with LaTeX and else it is probably a problem with your EPS file.

Comment: @Christian: If your question is satisfyingly answered, accept the corresponding answer. This gives you some reputation as well. ;)